# How to select rows which start with digit in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need to get rows starting with digit e.g. '1test', '32 test'.
I tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '[0-9]%'
```

as I used to do in MSSQL but it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 24):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name ~ '^[0-9]'
```

This uses a POSIX regular expression.

Comment: For anyone that might benefit from this, if you want the OPPOSITE (records that start with other-than a digit), use a preceding 'not' operator, i.e. `!~ '^[0-9]'`

Answer (score 7):

According to [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP), you can use `SIMILAR TO` instead of `LIKE` to do regex-like matching, and `~` to do full POSIX regex matching.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is probably faster than a regular expression, since regular expressions are CPU intensive:

```
SELECT ... FROM "table" WHERE substr(name, 1, 1) BETWEEN '0' AND '9';
```